# How to send multiple files using python's requests module and customize the header for each file?

Tags: python, python-requests

From http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/, I can find the way to customize the header for a single multipart-encoded file:

> You can set the filename, content_type and headers explicitly:

```
files = {'file': ('report.xls', open('report.xls', 'rb'),
                  'application/vnd.ms-excel', {'Expires': '0'})}
```

From http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/, I can find the way to send multiple multipart-encoded files:

> You can send multiple files in one request...To do that, just set
>   files to a list of tuples of (form_field_name, file_info):

```
multiple_files = [('images', ('foo.png', open('foo.png', 'rb'), 'image/png')),
                  ('images', ('bar.png', open('bar.png', 'rb'), 'image/png'))]
```

Let's say I want to send the above two pictures but I want to customize the header for the second picture. A reasonable thing to try is:

```
multiple_files = [('images', ('foo.png', open('foo.png', 'rb'), 'image/png')),
                  ('images', ('bar.png', open('bar.png', 'rb'), 'image/png', {'Expires': '0'}))]
```

However I got the following error:

```
In [49]: multiple_files = [('images', ('foo.png', "123", 'image/png')),
                           ('images', ('bar.png', "123", 'image/png', {'Expires': '0'}))]

In [50]: response = requests.post(
         url,
         headers={'accept': 'application/json'},
         files = multiple_files
         )
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-ef900c5109d7> in <module>()
      2         url,
      3         headers={'accept': 'application/json'},
----> 4         files = multiple_files
      5         )

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests-2.0.0-py2.7.egg/requests/api.pyc in post(url, data, **kwargs)
     86     """
     87
---> 88     return request('post', url, data=data, **kwargs)
     89
     90

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests-2.0.0-py2.7.egg/requests/api.pyc in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     42
     43     session = sessions.Session()
---> 44     return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     45
     46

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests-2.0.0-py2.7.egg/requests/sessions.pyc in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert)
    321             hooks = hooks,
    322         )
--> 323         prep = self.prepare_request(req)
    324
    325         proxies = proxies or {}

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests-2.0.0-py2.7.egg/requests/sessions.pyc in prepare_request(self, request)
    262             auth=merge_setting(auth, self.auth),
    263             cookies=merged_cookies,
--> 264             hooks=merge_setting(request.hooks, self.hooks),
    265         )
    266         return p

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests-2.0.0-py2.7.egg/requests/models.pyc in prepare(self, method, url, headers, files, data, params, auth, cookies, hooks)
    281         self.prepare_headers(headers)
    282         self.prepare_cookies(cookies)
--> 283         self.prepare_body(data, files)
    284         self.prepare_auth(auth, url)
    285         # Note that prepare_auth must be last to enable authentication schemes

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests-2.0.0-py2.7.egg/requests/models.pyc in prepare_body(self, data, files)
    411             # Multi-part file uploads.
    412             if files:
--> 413                 (body, content_type) = self._encode_files(files, data)
    414             else:
    415                 if data:

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests-2.0.0-py2.7.egg/requests/models.pyc in _encode_files(files, data)
    124                     fn, fp = v
    125                 else:
--> 126                     fn, fp, ft = v
    127             else:
    128                 fn = guess_filename(v) or k

ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

My question is that:
Can I customize the headers for individual files when multiple files exist?

Comment: You can't have independent headers because this is all sent as a single request, i.e. only one set of headers is sent. The headers are for the request, which contains multiple files. You can't independently set the cache on the individual files, the HTTP protocol doesn't support that. Either you will need to send them as two requests or set the cache for both.

Comment: No, not true. We can also define headers to describe the file we send. Following is a request I captured using nc (netcat), and I am only showing an exerpt because of words limit:

someHTTPHeader
...
--207f7f98b35342ad90c292be8cd2f082
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="content"; filename="yoooo"
Content-Type: 'application/octet-stream'

MTIz
--207f7f98b35342ad90c292be8cd2f082--

By "headers", I mean things like Content-Type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what a multipart HTTP request looks like, all the headers go at the beginning except the `content-type` and `content-disposition` for the multipart contents (they describe the content) and they only apply if the top level `content-type` is `multipart/form-data`:

```
POST /test HTTP/1.1
Host: host
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Charset: utf-8
Keep-Alive: 300
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------3141592654
Content-Length: 111

-----------------------------3141592654
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="foo.png"
Content-Type: image/png
[img-data]
-----------------------------3141592654
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="bar.png"
Content-Type: image/png
[img-data]
```

Comment: Yep, what if I want to do some customization? For example, if one file is Base 64 encoded, I would like to provide a header elaborating it.

Specifically:
Content-transfer-encoding: base64.

How can I add this for the second image if the second image is Base 64 encoded?

Comment: That you can do and is accepted by HTTP protocol, you just can't have `expires` or any other header, the three that are accepted, are `content-type`, `content-disposition` and `content-transfer-encoding`. But I'm unsure how you can do that through `requests`.

Comment: What version of `requests` are you using, it seems this feature may have been merged earlier this year: https://github.com/sigmavirus24/requests-toolbelt/issues/52

Comment: You are right and thanks for the clarification. I was just extending the example in the documentation of `requests` in which it adds a header `expires` for a single file.

Comment: You are right again. I upgraded from 2.0.0 to 2.7.0 and the bug went away. Thank you! How did you find this information? I did some google search for a while and finally I still have to resort to stack overflow...